# Foreach WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql, xml, lang

I'm trying to figure out how to handle multi language using xml and php? I want to be able to by default use english, but if a user has chosen a language, lets say german, I want to change the language to that. This part I can figure out, but I want to be able to, if a certain language string, has not been translated to german, pick the english version of that string. I have done this with regular php and mysql like this:

```
$language = "de";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."_countries WHERE con_id=$language"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) ;
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$userlang = $row['lang'];

$languagestring = array();
$res1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."_language WHERE lang = 'en'");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)){

    $langid = $row1['id'];

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."_language WHERE fk_id = $langid AND lang = '$userlang'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

    if(!$row){
        $languagestring[] = $row1['text'];
    } else {
        $str = $row['text'];
        $languagestring[] = $str;
    }

}
```

Now I have build my xml the same way as the db like this:

```
<data>
  <record id="1">
    <fk_id>0</fk_id>
    <lang>en</lang>
    <text>Network Error</text>
  </record>
  <record id="2">
    <fk_id>0</fk_id>
    <lang>en</lang>
    <text>There is a problem with the network!</text>
  </record>
  <record id="3">
    <fk_id>0</fk_id>
    <lang>en</lang>
    <text>OK</text>
  </record>
  <record id="4">
    <fk_id>1</fk_id>
    <lang>de</lang>
    <text>Das netvaerk sind corrupt!</text>
  </record>
```

'
How can i accomplish what I do with mysql with xml?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: You should learn how to make SQL JOIN's. All of your queries can be done with a single query (with no repetitions).

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Well, actually I wanted in this case to go around any db solution and just use XML. I was also wandering if the above example was easier if I used 2 xml documents, one for each language?

Answer (score 0):

There are standards to do such things, no need for XML!
For translation the most common way is using gettext, which is very popular on the Open Source world.

moreover, the MO files used in gettext are compiled files, which means they are WAY faster than parsing XML's.

take a look on http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php

To create PO and MO files I recommend using [PoEdit](http://www.poedit.net/) or [Virtaal](http://translate.sourceforge.net/wiki/virtaal/index).

Answer (score 0):

In XQuery, you would say something like this (not tested):

```
declare variable $userlang as xs:language external;

for $msg in /data/record[lang='en']
return (/data/record[lang=$userlang 
    and fk_id=$msg/@id], $msg)[1]
```

In English:  the variable `$userlang` is set externally to a language code.  For each `record` containing `<lang>en</lang>`, return a corresponding record in the user's language if one exists, otherwise return the English record.  (More concretely:  for each such record, make a sequence consisting of the corresponding record(s) in the user's language, followed by the English-language record, then take the first item in that sequence.)

In XSLT 2.0, you can do something very similar (I use XQuery in the example partly because it's more succinct and partly because its logic will feel more like the structure of your current code).

In other languages where you have access to XPath, you may be able to do roughly analogous things, although you are likely to have to replace the `return` expression with some application logic if you only have XPath 1.0.

Comment: Would it be easier if the languages are in different xml files, language_en.xml, language_de.xml?